# How do you win with a queen against a rook?

Tags: endgame, queens, rooks

It is considered that a Queen and King beats a Rook and King. Yet, the technique can be tricky. How is it done the best way?

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate: http://chess.stackexchange.com/q/883/167

Comment: @EdDean I like the answer (newshutz) better. It is a duplicate yet I think my formulation of the question is more clear and will lead to better search engine hits. Cheers.

Comment: I agree. I have merged the questions together, which added newshutz's answer to the old one. The old question can now be edited and re-titled as you suggest (which I also agree would be a good thing).